# How to validate empty report in JasperReports?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

My situation is when I'm not able to retrieve anything with my query, that is found inside the jasper file, a report is still generated.

I'm using this line of code to generate report.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReportStream, params, jdbcConnection);
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
Exporter jrExporter = getJRExporter(format, jasperPrint, baos);
jrExporter.exportReport();
bytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

Is there a way to use the exporter object to detect if my report is empty?
I have tried to validate null using the byteArray then converted to String when producing a pdf format.

However I cannot easily check if byteArray is null since it produces this output despite returning no results from my query:

```
%PDF-1.4
%����
1 0 obj <</Length 45/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream
x�3P0T�5T0P0�4�ɹ\�\N!\�f
���
!)\�!\�\\
```

Comment: You can avoid this problem by setting whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" at property of report

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set on `jasperReport` tag `whenNoDataType="NoPages"` or remove `whenNoDataType` attribute (default is "NoPages")

Check how many pages there are in the `JasperPrint`, if **0** you have **NoData**

```
    JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReportStream, params, jdbcConnection);
    List<JRPrintPage> pages = print.getPages();
    if (pages.size()==0){
            //No pages, do not export instead do other stuff
    }
```

Comment: Hi Petter, I have tried using option 2 and it still returns a page size of 1 despite having no result from queries in the Jasper Report. Is it because the pdf format returns garbage despite having no results from the query?

Comment: With this solution you are not checking the pdf but the JasperPrint be sure to set attribute whenNoDataType="NoPages". Note: they are not options but sequence, I have removed 1 and 2 so answer is more clear..

Comment: I have tried whenNoDataType="NoPages" and a pdf is still produced despite having no result. Btw, thanks for replying.

Comment: what is your page.size() value?, the pdf always produce if you call the exporter, you should not call it if pages.size()==0

Comment: I apologized for saying it didn't work. It works now. Thank you Petter.